# Laravel 4.2 - Can't update my database when user session timeout with Event

Tags: php, session, laravel

I currently have a problem with my laravel(4.2) app.

I want to update my database when the user is offline by the end of session (Automatic).

So I put the lifetime session to 1 minute for testing.

I create an event file :

```
<?php

Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
    $user->is_online        = 1;
    $user->save();
});

Event::listen('auth.logout', function($user)
{
    $user->is_online        = 0;
    $user->save();
});
```

Everything works perfectly when I log in or log out manually but when I get automatically disconnected by the end of the session it does not work.

If you have an idea I would appreciate

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot detect when a user closes their browser or navigates off your site using  PHP

Instead, your best bet is most likely to store each user's last activity time.

Create a column in your user table along the lines of 'last_activity'.
Whenever a user loads a page, update their last_activity to the current time.
To get a list of who's online, just query the database for users with last_activity values more recent than 10 min or 20 min.

you can set session time using this

$_SESSION['time'] = time();

Answer (score 2):

You have to detect if the session has ended by comparing it with the current time. For instance:

```
if ((time() - Session::activity()) > (Config::get('session.lifetime') * 60))
{
   // Session expired
   Event::fire('session.expired');
}
```

Hook into the `session.expired` event and do whatever you want.

Comment: and where to put this code, so it will work as you mentioned.